# Changing the standard blue color of the form's control box in

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, background

is there a way I can change the color of the form's controlbox in a .NET winform application i.e the box the has the close-minimize-maximize buttons? I need to change that blue color to match the colors of the different controls within that form.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's drawn by the system, so I don't think it's going to exactly be "easy".

The only thing I can think of is to turn the system buttons off, then manually draw & handle your own.

Comment: Agree. Addendum: Don't do that, unless you're about to create a fully-skinned application and know what you're doing. A half-baked skinning solution will likely break in the future.